# changing swagger curl (localhost instead of 0.0.0.0)

Tags: json, docker-compose, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to change the URL of my swagger UI from `0.0.0.0` to `localhost` (see image below)

[image]

I'm using a docker compose with a swagger image.

```
version: '3'

services:
  api-postgrest:
    image: another-url.com/postgrest:1.0.0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - database-postgres
    environment:
      - PGRST_DB_URI=postgres://${DATABASE_USER}:${DATABASE_PASSWORD}@database-postgres:5432/${DATABASE_NAME}
      - PGRST_DB_SCHEMA=${PGRST_DB_SCHEMA} # public
      - PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE=${PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE} # web_anon

  database-postgres:
    image: postgres:16
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER} # postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD} # postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME} # postgres
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  swagger:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      API_URL: http://localhost:3000/

volumes:
  pg_data:
```

My current solution after some researching was to add a json configuration file as you can see below, with the `SWAGGER_JSON`.

```
  swagger:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      API_URL: http://localhost:3000/
      SWAGGER_JSON: swagger.json
```

The json file looks like this

```json
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "The YOLO Json",
        "description": "I'm losing my stuff",
        "version": "0.0.1"
    },

    "host": "127.0.0.1:3000",
    "schemes": [
        "https"
    ]
}
```

Yet it is not working. My question would be the following, is the path for `SWAGGER_JSON` correct and also the json correct in its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `SWAGGER_JSON`, you don't need to specify `API_URL` as that seems to be the URL from which to load the swagger.json. Also from the `swagger` service definition in the question, it doesn't look like the `swagger.json` file has been mounted into the container. And as the `swagger.json` in the question didn't have any operations, I used the [petstore swagger json](https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json) instead, changing the URL to `127.0.0.1:3000` like in the question. With those things I ended up with a `docker-compose.yml` file like the below:

```
services:
  swagger:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui:v5.11.6
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SWAGGER_JSON: /specs/swagger.json
    volumes:
      - ./swagger.json:/specs/swagger.json
```

With the above compose file, the outbound requests do show the expected host:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://127.0.0.1:3000/v2/pet/1234' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

You can find all the changes including the swagger.json used on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/random-demo/commit/5573e5bb383a6369d786c4337d9045d949f4d533).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either one of them:-

I would prefer swagger JSON, as below

```
swagger:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SWAGGER_JSON: /specs/swagger.json
    volumes:
      - ./swagger.json:/specs/swagger.json
```

The entries in your `swagger.json` looks good